# Convert 'yyyy-mm-dd' strings to date type variables for MySQL from Java

Tags: java, mysql, date

I am using JXL API for reading in the values from Excel File. I want to convert the above specified format into Date type Variable to load into MYSQL Database. Please Help me.

```
![Error Shown: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date

at SoccerDatabase.read(SoccerDatabase.java:74)
at SoccerDatabase.main(SoccerDatabase.java:122)][1]


static Date[] dob=new Date[1000];
Cell cell5=sheet.getCell(4,i);
dob[i]=cell5.getContents();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet splits the date string by '-'(hyphen) and creates a `Date` object

```
    String[] split = cell5.getContents().split("-");    //split the date string by '-' (hyphen)
    int year = Integer.parseInt(split[0]) - 1900;       //subtract 1900 as Date constructor take years after 1900
    int month = Integer.parseInt(split[1]) - 1;         //subtract 1 as Date constructor take months in range 0-11
    int date = Integer.parseInt(split[2]);
    dob[i] = new Date(year, month, date);               //Create java.sql.Date object from the values
```

Also, remember that the `Date` class to be used is `java.sql.Date`, **NOT** <strike>`java.util.Date`</strike>

Refer the JavaDoc for the `java.sql.Date` constructor [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Thank you Shrinivas. I removed the -1900 because I wanted yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

You will get the error because `cell5.getContents()` return a string representation of the date. But you are trying to assign it to a `Date` object directly.

Parse it to a date instead with something like this,

```
dob[i]=new SimpleDateFormat("''yyyy-MM-dd''").parse(cell5.getContents());
```

Edit based on your comment:

In SimpleDateFormat, `'` single quotes are used to specify literal characters.

Eg: If your date is like `2015-05-10T` you will parse it with `yyyy-MM-dd'T'`

So, if you have a single quote in your date as well, use 2 single quotes `''` to specify it.

Comment: Thank you....There are single inverted commas. ('yyyy-mm-dd'). I did try your solution. Still no good.